# Accessing a device on a different subnet

Tags: networking, router, ip, putty, gateway

I have only one router and its gateway ip and mask is 192.168.1.1 and 255.255.255.0.  My PC uses dhcp, and thus has an ip in the 192.168.1 block.  I also have a linux box with a static ip of 192.168.1.10.

I also have a raspberry pi who's static ip is 10.1.4.5 and who's gateway is 10.1.4.1.

How can I access the pi from the pc using putty?

If not possible, what about from the linux box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign an additional IP address to one of your computers in the `10.1.4.5/whatever` subnetwork. I assume (but don't know first hand) that this is a simple task on a Linux box. Windows computers also support adding an additional IP to an existing network interface, although you need to use a static address for the NIC's primary address.

Once one of your computers has an address in the Raspberry Pi's subnetwork, you'll be able to access it via its current IP address without a problem.